# Not able to access static variable of another package's class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, static-members

I have a class in one package and another class in another package.
In first package i have a public static variable which i want to access from second class.

Here is my first class's code :

```
package first;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class first{
public static WebDriver driver;
}
```

Here is my second class's code :

```
package second;
import first.*;

public class second{
first.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).click();
}
```

My IDE is displaying error in 'first.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).click();' this line.

Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: sorry my mistake, now i've edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are trying to call a method - `findElement` - not from within a method, which is invalid. You should put that call either in a constructor, in a method or in a static initializer block.

For example :

```
public class second {

    static {
        first.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).click();
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's the proper place to call this method, since I don't know what's its purpose.